# Credentials to use google ADMIN SDK API

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-workspace, google-admin-sdk

I've been tasked to write a short script that will add a user to a group in google workspace. However, I'm really new to the documentation and its not making any sense to me.
I created a new account on google workspace, added my domain and confirmed it, then went to the admin console and created a new user and then a new group.
Then, I went to cloud console, created a new project, enabled  and created a new service account, enabled Admin SDK API and associated the service account with that API. I also downloaded the service account credentials to run with the script, and I even added "domain wide delegation from what I could find in a github link but it doesn't seem to work.
I just simply want to add my `user2@example.com` to `testgroup@example.com`. Can anyone point me to the right direction? Thanks.

This is the python script:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# Define your service account credentials and group email
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('service_account_credentials.json')
group_email = 'testgroup@example.com'
user_email = 'user2@example.com'

# Build the service client
service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials)

# Add the user to the group
service.members().insert(groupKey=group_email, body={'email': user_email}).execute()
```

This returns the following error:

```
 <HttpError 403 when requesting https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/testgroup%40example.com/members?alt=json returned "Not Authorized to access this resource/api". Details: "[{'message': 'Not Authorized to access this resource/api', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'forbidden'}]">
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I fixed it. The scope to add to group is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member` which I had not added in the domain wide delegation. Secondly, I also impersonated as the admin account to do it. This is my final script:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# Define your service account credentials and group email
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user', 
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group' ,
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member'
]
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('service_account_credentials.json',scopes=SCOPES ,subject="admin@example.com")
group_email = 'testgroup@example.com'
user_email = 'user@example.com'


# Build the service client
service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials)

# Add the user to the group
service.members().insert(groupKey=group_email, body={'email': user_email}).execute()
```